# How to get Geocoder’s results on the LatLng’s country language?

Tags: java, android, locale, reverse-geocoding

I use reverse geocoding in my app to transform LatLng objects to string addresses. I have to get its results not on device’s default language, but on the language of the country where given location is settled. Is there a way to do this? 
Here’s my code:

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List addresses; 
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1);
    } 
    catch (IOException | IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException ex) {
        addresses = null;
    }
    return addresses;
```

Comment: You mean if the device is in English and you're looking at Beijing, it should actually return the Mandarin characters?

Comment: @TeoInke not sure about Mandarin characters, I mean it should return french names in France, german in Germany, italian in Italy, etc

Comment: Ok, got it. From what I found it's possible to set the language on the JS API, but not on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, Geocoder returns address text in device locale(language).

1 From first element of "addresses" list, get Country Code.

```
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    String countryCode = address.getCountryCode
```

Then returns Country Code (e.g. "MX")

2 Get Country Name.

```
   String langCode = null;

   Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
   for (Locale localeIn : locales) {
          if (countryCode.equalsIgnoreCase(localeIn.getCountry())) {
                langCode = localeIn.getLanguage();
                break;
          }
    }
```

3 Instantiate Locale and Geocoder again, and request again.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(langCode, countryCode);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, locale);

    List addresses; 
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude,         location.longitude, 1);
        } 
        catch (IOException | IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException ex) {
            addresses = null;
        }
        return addresses;
```

This worked for me, hopefully for you too!

Comment: thank you, worked for me too, except I don't create new Locale and use object from step 2.